# is there anyway to show dotted lines in google org chart API between 2 nodes?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, orgchart

i was [looking at using the google org chart to display my org chart](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html).  Does this support having dotted lines between relationships as opposed to the default regular line

Answer (score 1):

No - it is pretty basic. You can make specific nodes in the chart have a dotted border though, eg:

```
data.setRowProperty(2, 'style', 'border-style: dotted');
```

Comment: are you saying this would have a dotted line around the border of the person ?  Also, any other alternatives?

Comment: yep - not very dramatic but it might help :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery('.google-visualization-orgchart-linebottom, .google-visualization-orgchart-lineleft, .google-visualization-orgchart-lineright').css('border','1px dotted #cccccc');

Comment: Also, do this only after chart is drawn.  It's a hack but it works great for me.

Comment: wouldn't this make all the lines dotten (instead of just the relationship between two items?