# What is the equivalent of chls property for dotted line in google chart JS API?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I need the equivalent of [chls](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/line_charts.html#gcharts_line_styles) property to be able to draw dotted line charts with the JavaScript API like the `chls` parameter does in the regular google chart API.

I've tried the [given tricks here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719552/is-there-anyway-to-show-dotted-lines-in-google-org-chart-api) but it doesn't work for me.

This is my actual code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                data.addColumn('string', "Nombre d'exécution du programme");

        data.addColumn('number', 'Création du graphe pour 10 exécutions');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Resolution de Dijkstra pour 10 exécutions');

        data.addColumn('number', 'Création du graphe pour 100 exécutions');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Resolution de Dijkstra pour 100 exécutions');

        data.addColumn('number', 'Création du graphe pour 1000 exécutions');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Resolution de Dijkstra pour 1000 exécutions');

        data.addColumn('number', 'Création du graphe pour 10000 exécutions');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Resolution de Dijkstra pour 10000 exécutions');

        data.addColumn('number', 'Création du graphe pour 100000 exécutions');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Resolution de Dijkstra pour 100000 exécutions');

        data.addRows([
          ['1', // Nombre de tests
            911.111111111111, 981.507773124157, // 10 exécutions
            5916.34265646557, 8652.74074074074, // 100
            15873.293352048, 38374.6331504402, // 1000
            20583.9468919734, 54833.2671045558, // 10000
            21731.123388582, 62344.9206884914, // 100000
          ],
          ['10', 
            660.045054269916, 873.872505846266, // 10
            1479.11974962178, 3809.3591031963, // 100
            2365.02966174325, 5291.4404255426, // 1000
            2489.9768981046, 6026.41413062173, // 10000
            74966.0679996439, 6855.2716011857, // 100000
          ],
          ['100', 
            257.002598902686, 449.898770994325, // 10
            1117.85291997813, 664.696852512432, // 100
            411.255444801189, 706.801182419083, // 1000
            502.157411124161, 4589.16141015407, // 10000
            8347.894845246, 5269.57442418582, // 100000
          ],
          ['1000', 
            147.489910803794, 154.020514119286, // 10
            146.285394503668, 165.264695318371, // 100
            178.955165911359, 534.771450920607, //1000
            895.70893745921, 690.426997324878, // 10000
            1436.27709770908, 1631.77983702272, // 100000
          ],
          ['10000', 
            104.714581363082, 106.393139452612, // 10
            112.895078296546, 109.63484225748, // 100
            233.803672029444, 246.491106857861, //1000
            506.280370709875, 232.445295937225, // 10000
            570.571422701139, 412.694573393414, // 100000
          ]
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: "100%", height: "1000",
          title: 'C# - TEMPS MAXIMUM',
              colors: [
            '#2A00FF', '#2A00FF',
            '#2BFF00', '#2BFF00',
            '#FFEA00', '#FFEA00',
            '#FF8C1A', '#FF8C1A',
            '#FF0000', '#FF0000', 
            '#B30000', '#B30000'
          ],
          vAxis: {
            title: '% par rapport à la moyenne',
            viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
            viewWindow: {
              //max: 8000,
              min: 100,
            },
            gridlines: {
              count: 18,
            }
          },
          hAxis: {
            title: "Nombre de résolution d'algorithme Dijkstra (avec création du graphe)",
          },
            series: {0:{lineWidth: '1'}, 1:{lineWidth: '2'},
                    2:{lineWidth: '1'}, 3:{lineWidth: '2'},
                    4:{lineWidth: '1'}, 5:{lineWidth: '2'},
                    6:{lineWidth: '1'}, 7:{lineWidth: '2'},
                    8:{lineWidth: '1'}, 9:{lineWidth: '2'},
                    10:{lineWidth: '1'}, 11:{lineWidth: '2'}

            }

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('average'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="average"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code gives the following error (see http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ25U/): Uncaught Error:  "format+en,default,corechart.I.js:54Uncaught Error: Row given with size different than 10 (the number of columns in the table)."

Comment: Sorry I've deleted a line... See the edit, thanks. Added `   data.addColumn('string', "Nombre d'exécution du programme");` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is a inconvenient solution because I could not find anywhere in the Visualization api to do this. (I think there must be though, because if you search through the javascript, you come up with some obfuscated google code that mentions 'stroke-dasharray')

But here's a possible solution:

Use stroke-dasharray css property for `<path>`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray

In order to get this to work, you'll need to append a css `<link>` to the `<head>` of the `<iframe>` that google visualization api creates:

Put this at the end of your create function:

```
    chart.draw(data, options);

    var cssLink = document.createElement('link');
    cssLink.href = "chart.css";
    cssLink.rel = "stylesheet";
    cssLink.type = "text/css";
    frames[0].document.head.appendChild(cssLink);
```

}

Create a chart.css in the same directory and put this into it:

```
path{stroke-dasharray:5,5}
```

And you have: http://vigrond.com/test/strokedasharray.php

I will leave it up to you to decide which paths have a dash or not.  I am sure you can do some javascript arrays to correlate with your data object and the actual `<path>` elements to add stroke-dasharray to them, and create a little sub-framework of your own.

Comment: Thanks it works great! I have to wait the 24H period to award the bounty ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, trying to find and found your solution. However, I can't seem to figure out how to display only a selected line as a dashed line. But I found an [experimental role functionality](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/roles.html#certaintyrole). With that you can simulate the dashed line. Below is a [default playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#bar_chart) version. Changed the chartype to `LineChart` instead of `BarChart`. The new code becomes:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var line_data = [true, false, true, false];
        var raw_data = [
            ['Austria', 1336060, 1538156, 1576579, 1600652, 1968113, 1901067],
            ['Bulgaria', 400361, 366849, 440514, 434552, 393032, 517206],
            ['Denmark', 1001582, 1119450, 993360, 1004163, 979198, 916965],
            ['Greece', 997974, 941795, 930593, 897127, 1080887, 1056036]
        ];

        var years = [2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008];

        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        for (var i = 0; i  < raw_data.length; ++i) {
            data.addColumn('number', raw_data[i][0]);
            data.addColumn({type:'boolean',role:'certainty'});
        }


        data.addRows(years.length);

        for (var j = 0; j < years.length; ++j) {
            data.setValue(j, 0, years[j].toString());
        }
        for (var i = 0; i  < raw_data.length; ++i) {
            for (var j = 1; j  < raw_data[i].length; ++j) {
                data.setValue(j-1, (i*2)+1, raw_data[i][j]);
                data.setValue(j-1, (i*2)+2, line_data[i]);
            }
        }

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).
                draw(data,
                {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
                    width:600, height:400,
                    vAxis: {title: "Year"},
                    hAxis: {title: "Cups"}}
        );
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've defined a `line_data` array with booleans. `True` means solid, `false` means dashed. In the first loop I'm adding the new column with the role `certainty`. In the double loop, the value of `i` is adjusted to fill the correct cell. `line_data` is used to fill the new columns.

The result will show two dashed lines